# Laravel 5.5.* Cookie::get return encrypted cookie value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I try

```
Cookie::queue(Cookie::forever('test', 'TEST'));
    $value = Cookie::get('test');
and get like this eyJpdiI6ImNzUFNON0N0c1UzRUlWMTVFQ01rMnc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiU2JadHRhRFRcL3RES2VNT1dPOE84YTR0d0NQTnhiUEs3bllcL3ZiczYzaFhxc2h0NGR0MzllNmtJcDRqZnMza2NCK1FlZ...
```

Laravel should automatically encrypt or not?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you expect and what you want, please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Cookies in laravel are automatically encrypted

Comment: if automatically encrypted why Cookie::get('test'); return me this  "eyJpdiI6ImNzUFNON0N0c1UzRUlWMTVFQ01rMnc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiU2JadHRhRFRcL3RES2VN"